# Why does the Armorer nearly interrupt the fight?

Tags: star-wars, the-mandalorian, the-book-of-boba-fett

In episode 5 of The Book of Boba Fett, Paz Vizsla fights Din Djarin for ownership of the darksaber. Immediately after, the Armorer asks each of them if they have ever removed their helmet. The question seemed extremely abrupt to me—I didn’t think the battle was even decisively finished. Plus it seemed a little late—if it’s such an important component of being a Mandalorian (to the Armorer at least), wouldn’t she have asked him well before the fight?

My question is this: is there an in-universe reason the Armorer would nearly interrupt the fight to ask if they have removed their helmets? Or is it probably just a pacing issue?

Comment: Din already won - had a blade by opponents' throat. I think that perhaps she asked, because guys nearly killed each other and needed a reminder.

Answer (score 5):

Her question was a direct reference to The Way of the Mandalore, the creed by which the Children of the Watch lived by. This was a duel of honor and succession. This question would have been posed to determine their individual honor (and thus their right to be a part of the clan) as well as remind them of their brotherhood, since they had just fought a duel.

Edit: Upon rewatching, I noticed that Din Djarin had a vibroknife to Paz Vizsla's throat. The Armorer likely also was attempting to prevent Djarin from killing Vizsla, as they were rebuilding the covert and there were only three of them so far.